# Understanding theme hooks and template preprocessors

Tags: theming

In hook_theme for the poll module in drupal 7 the following is defined:

```
function poll_theme() {
  $theme_hooks = array(
    'poll_vote' => array(
      'template' => 'poll-vote',
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
    'poll_choices' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
    ),
    'poll_results' => array(
      'template' => 'poll-results',
      'variables' => array('raw_title' => NULL, 'results' => NULL, 'votes' => NULL, 'raw_links' => NULL, 'block' => NULL, 'nid' => NULL, 'vote' => NULL),
    ),
    'poll_bar' => array(
      'template' => 'poll-bar',
      'variables' => array('title' => NULL, 'votes' => NULL, 'total_votes' => NULL, 'vote' => NULL, 'block' => NULL),
    ),
  );
  // The theme system automatically discovers the theme's functions and
  // templates that implement more targeted "suggestions" of generic theme
  // hooks. But suggestions implemented by a module must be explicitly
  // registered.
  $theme_hooks += array(
    'poll_results__block' => array(
      'template' => 'poll-results--block',
      'variables' => $theme_hooks['poll_results']['variables'],
    ),
    'poll_bar__block' => array(
      'template' => 'poll-bar--block',
      'variables' => $theme_hooks['poll_bar']['variables'],
    ),
  );
  return $theme_hooks;
}
```

In `function poll_view_voting($form, &$form_state, $node, $block = FALSE) {` there is `$form['#theme'] = 'poll_vote';`

How does this work and what does this to?

Also there is this function:

```
function template_preprocess_poll_vote(&$variables) {
  $form = $variables['form'];
  $variables['choice'] = drupal_render($form['choice']);
  $variables['title'] = check_plain($form['#node']->title);
  $variables['vote'] = drupal_render($form['vote']);
  $variables['rest'] = drupal_render_children($form);
  $variables['block'] = $form['#block'];
  if ($variables['block']) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'poll_vote__block';
  }
}
```

I was able to create a function theme_preprocess_poll_vote(&$variables) which I was able to change the output. Is their a document that explains how this all works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest you read everything you can in the [Theming guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme).  It looks like you're specifically looking for [this](http://drupal.org/node/341628) part of it though.